# Conversion Tools, Layer to KML

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml, arcgis-10.5

I have converted the GIS layer to KML.

When I open it in Google Earth, it opens my map in the sea.

What's wrong?

Comment: Probably the coordinate reference system (CRS). A KML is always in WGS84 (EPSG:4326). What is the CRS of your source layer? (http://www.gdal.org/drv_kml.html)

Comment: It is WGS84_UTN_Zon42N

Comment: Be sure that the source data (EPSG:32642) are exported in WGS84 (EPSG:4326).

Comment: If you used ArcGIS Desktop to  convert a layer to KML what were the precise steps that you performed (all tools and parameter values)?

Answer (score 2):

Could be one of two things;

1. Check your layers coordinate systems, make sure that it's WGS84,
   EPSG:4326 pre/post conversion. If this layer is a shapefile you 
   can see the projection in the .prj file (or in layer properties).
2. If its point data and you're generating this layer yourself, make sure you 
   have the correct fields specified for lat/lon.